# Prisma how to get data from relation as using 'where'?

Tags: prisma, gql

my User prisma schema User model has `like[]`:

```
model User {
  likes Like[]
}
```

and Like model has `createdAt`.

```
model Like {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  userId Int
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())

  @@unique([feedId, userId])
}
```

I want to get data how many times `user` links to `Like` model in `this month`.
So I get data like below.

```
export default {
  Query: {
    seeAllLikeOrder: protectedResolver(() => {
      const startOfMonth = new Date(
        moment().startOf("month").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm").substring(0, 10)
      );
      const endOfMonth = new Date(
        moment().endOf("month").format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm").substring(0, 10)
      );
      return client.user.findMany({
        where: {
          likes: {
            createdAt: {
              gte: startOfMonth,
              lt: endOfMonth,
            },
          },
        },
        orderBy: {
          likes: {
            _count: "desc",
          },
        },
        take: 10,
      });
    }),
  },
};
```

But error comes:

[image]

I think I can't use according to error message.

```
where: {
          likes: {
            createdAt: {
              gte: startOfMonth,
              lt: endOfMonth,
            },
          },
        },
```

But i don't understand why.

Because User has Like model and Like has createdAt field.

in this case, how to get data that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty descriptive as to what's going on: `createdAt` is not a valid property of `LikeListRelationFilter`, and that type only has the properties `every`, `some`, or `none`.

Your issue is the nested select when querying the `likes` field:

```js
return client.user.findMany({
  where: {
    likes: { // This line
      createdAt: {
        gte: startOfMonth,
        lt: endOfMonth,
      },
    },
  },
  orderBy: {
    likes: {
      _count: "desc",
    },
  },
  take: 10,
});
```

In Prisma, when you are querying a field and filtering based on the value of a nested field, the API for querying that nested array field will be different than if you were querying `prisma.like.findMany`. In your situation, your query must look something like this:

```js
return client.user.findMany({
  where: {
    likes: { // This line is different
      // Find any user where at least one of their likes abides by this condition.
      // Replace with "every" to only search for users where ALL of their likes abide by this condition,
      // or "none" to only search for users where NONE of their likes abide by this condition.
      some: { 
        createdAt: {
          gte: startOfMonth,
          lt: endOfMonth,
        },
      }
    },
  },
  orderBy: {
    likes: {
      _count: "desc",
    },
  },
  take: 10,
});
```

Documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting

If the nested field was a single item (not an array of items), you would use `is` or `isNot` instead. Here you have an array, so you have to use `every`, `some`, or `none`.

Comment: I learn a lot thanks.